# share service data b/w two independent controllers using $emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to share my service data b/w two controllers and my controllers are independent. How can I achieve this?

Here is my service:

```
angular.module("myApp").service('emt', function($http,$rootScope) 
{
    this.value1 = "";
    this.value2 = "";
});
```

Here is my first controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('emitCtrl', function($scope,emt,$modal,$rootScope){
    $scope.user=emt;
    $scope.myArray=[];
    $scope.send=function(user){  
        $scope.myArray.push({value1:$scope.user.value1,value2:$scope.user.value2});
        console.log($scope.user);
        $scope.user.value1="";
        $scope.user.value2="";


        //firing an event towords upword direction using emit.
        $rootScope.$emit('myEmitEvent', 'emt');  //  emt is the name of service.
        };

        //modeal for show emit data
        $scope.open=function(){
            alert("hello its emit !");
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '../../../view/emitPageModal.html',
                controller: 'myEventCtrl'
            });

        };

    });
```

Here is my second controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myEventCtrl', function($scope,emt,$modalInstance,$rootScope){
    $scope.demo=false;
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $scope.demo=true;
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

// for catching an  event raised by emit 
$rootScope.$on('myEmitEvent', function (event, data) {
    $scope.myemitedData=data.emt;
    console.log(data.emt); 
    console.log($scope.myemitedData);
    // 'Some data'

    });
});
```

Here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal-header" ng-hide="demo">
    <h4>Modal Dialog</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Example paragraph with some text.</p>

    <p>Your name is :{{user.value1}}</p>
    <p>Your number is :{{user.value2}}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ok()">Okay</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services are nothing but entities that can be shared. These can have complex objects, functions etc. In order to share them services has to return them like following :

```
      angular.module("myApp").service('emt', function($http, $rootScope) {
      var myObj = {
        value1: "",
        value2: ""
      }
      var func = function(){
       console.log('test')
}
      return {
        obj: myObj,
        publicFun : func
      }
    });
```

Now the variable myObj will be available wherever emt is injected.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('emitCtrl', function($scope,emt,$modal,$rootScope){
     $scope.user=emt.obj;
});
```

This emt.obj will always have the latest value in any controller it is shared in.

Comment: it is best solution solution thanking you .my code work fine now .

Answer (score 0):

You just want to set values in your emit service inside the first controller (emitCtrl). After inject that service (emit) to second controller (myEventCtrl) you can get the values you set inside the first controller by using emit service. No need to use **$emit** service. I appended a sample code just get an idea.

```js
angular.module("myApp").service('emt', function($http, $rootScope) {
  this.value1 = "";
  this.value2 = "";
});


angular.module('myApp').controller('emitCtrl', function($scope, emt, $modal, $rootScope) {

  /*Sample code to set value in first controller*/
  emt.value1 = "my value1"
  emt.value2 = "my value2"

});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myEventCtrl', function($scope, emt, $modalInstance, $rootScope) {
  /* You can access the value of value1 and value2 inside second controller using emt service*/

  var myVal1 = emt.value1;
  var myVal2 = emt.value2
});
```

Comment: thank you so much you save my time thanks once again .

Comment: happy to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

> You can use service and inject in any controller you want to use.All the services except $scope in angular are singleton.

**Sample Test Case**

```js
angular.module("Test", [])
  .service('shared', function() {
    this.user = "Dev";
    this.age = "25";

    this.setData = function(data) {
      this.user = data.user;
      this.age = data.age;
    }
    this.getData = function() {
      return {
        user: this.user,
        age: this.age
      }
    }
  })
  .controller("ctr1", function($scope, shared) {
    this.data = shared.getData();
    shared.setData({
      user: "John",
      age: 25
    });
  })
  .controller("ctr2", function($scope, shared) {
    this.data = shared.getData();
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <div ng-app="Test">
    <div ng-controller="ctr1 as ctr1">
      **Controller 1**
      <p>
        {{ctr1.data.user}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ctr2 as ctr2">
      **Controller 2**
      <p>
        {{ctr2.data.user}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```